# CodeBlocks - Troubles with building c++ project

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i have a problem with building c++ project in CodeBLocks.
everytime i want to build my project i get only this error "mingw32-g++.exe: error: move: No such file or directory".

Photos:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/beznzvutgd.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/82384834.png/

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the MingW toolchain, since codeblocks is just an IDE, you need a compiler to make it useable. Download MingW (google it) then open `CodeBlocks->Settings->compiler and debugger`. Select `Toolchain executables` tab then browse to where you extracted the MingW from the `Compiler's installation directory`. I hope this helps.